# ng-pattern for excluding a list of characters

Tags: regex, angularjs

I am looking for the ng-pattern for my input field which is excluding these special characters:

```
[ ] : ; | = + * ? < > / \ ,
```

I don't want the user input has these characters above. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

You have to escape the `\` and the `]`:

```
ng-pattern="/^[^[\]:;|=+*?<>/\\,]+$/"
```

pattern automatically adds the `/^` and the `$/` so:

```
pattern="[^[\]:;|=+*?<>/\\,]+"
```

---

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app'>
<form name="myForm">
  <input name="field" ng-model="something" ng-pattern="/^[^[\]:;|=+*?<>/\\,]+$/">
  {{ myForm.field.$error }}
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks DTing. I want to add the " to this list but couldn't make it work  ng-pattern="/^[^[\]:;|=+*?<>/\\,]+$/\"" Any suggestion how to add " to this list

Comment: if you just want to add `"`, you can change your double quotes on the outside to single quotes and use: `<input name="field" ng-model="something" ng-pattern='/^[^[\]:;|=+*?<>/\\,"]+$/'>` If you want both single and double quotes, I think you need the string declared in your controller and use `ng-pattern="{{ ctrl.regexpattern }}"`

Comment: Thanks a lot DTing. That's work for me. again thanks

Comment: No problem. Welcome to stackoverflow. If this answers your question [please mark it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for

```
^[^[:;|=+*?<>\/\\,\]]+$
```

You can see what it does at the [following link](http://regexper.com/#%5E%5B%5E%5B%3A%3B%7C%3D%2B*%3F%3C%3E%5C%2F%5C%5C%2C%5C%5D%5D%2B%24)

Comment: Sorry I meant pattern. I have tried this pattern="^[^[:;|=+*?<>\/\\,\]]+$"  and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
"^[^\[\]:;|=\+\*\?<>\/\\]+$"
```

if it doesn't work with HTML then u can use

`"^[^\\[\\]:;|=\\+\\*\\?<>\\/\\\]+$"`